# Unable to access db file when installing deb file created using electron-builder

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron-builder

I am trying to wrap an existing nodeJS application in electron-js and build the .deb package using electron-builder.

When I build the deb file with extraResources config to include my sqlite db and try to run the app by simply extracting the content of deb file, sqlite db is accessible to app without any problems.

However, if I try to install the deb file using dpkg, the applicaiton is installed but cannot find the db file when the application is run from app icon created by ubuntu in it's application. If on the other hand if I try to run the installed app from /opt/app_name/ it works as intended.

What steps can I take to mitigate this behavior?

I have tried specifying extraResources config in the package.json file, also giving path to node module that requires the db file works in devlopment mode but gives the path of asar archive in the built app.

Comment: You can try to build your app with asar disabled and see if that is the issue. If not, it might be some relative paths issue so I am not sure how your project is structured but you can put some logs and check out that the paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

we have changed to using AppImage for packaging and distributing the app, as it gives more freedom in portability and does not require app to be installed and AppImages can be updated using auto-updater provided by electron builder.